# Show long form of a glossary entry multiple times

Tags: glossaries-extra

Normally, the `glossaries-extra` package displays the long form of an abbreviation only the first time.

I would like to set the number of times that the long form of abbreviations are shown, before it starts showing the short form.

For example:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{glossaries-extra}

\setabbreviationstyle{long-only-short-only}
\glssetcategoryattribute{shortperiod}{discardperiod}{true}
\glssetcategoryattribute{shortperiod}{retainfirstuseperiod}{true}

\newabbreviation[category=shortperiod]{etc}{etc.}{etcetera}

\begin{document}
  \gls{etc}. \gls{etc}. \gls{etc}. \gls{etc}. 
\end{document}
```

Results in:

```
etcetera. etc. etc. etc.
```

However, I would like to set the number of times that the long form is displayed. E.g., if I set the long form to be shown three times, the output would be:

```
etcetera. etcetera. etcetera. etc.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can easily do that. AFAIK you'd need to turn on counting and then check the counter in order to respond accordingly. There are alternative ways, though.

`\glsreset{etc}` will unset a flag corresponding to the first use. Hence, afterwards on the next issue of `\gls{...}`, you will get the "first form" or "full form" depending on your global settings. In [glossary-extra](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/glossaries-extra), the equivalent is `\gls[prereset]{etc}`, which combines `\glsreset{...}` and `\gls{...}` in one macro.

I think if you want to typeset a term in long or full form in specific place after the first use, the recommended macros are `\glsxtrfull{...}`, `\glsxtrlong{...}`, or `\glsxtrshort{...}` for the full, long, and short forms, respectively; additionally, these macros are independent to global settings.

This code will produce the expected output

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{glossaries-extra}

\setabbreviationstyle{long-only-short-only}
\glssetcategoryattribute{shortperiod}{discardperiod}{true}
\glssetcategoryattribute{shortperiod}{retainfirstuseperiod}{true}

\newabbreviation[category=shortperiod]{etc}{etc.}{etcetera}

\begin{document}
\gls{etc}. \glsxtrlong{etc}. \glsxtrlong{etc}. \gls{etc}.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks @Celdor! I will do it manually. I was hoping there was an easier way, since I might mistakenly add an extra `\gls{etc}` somewhere in between the first few `\glsxtrlong{etc}` entries. In my real case, they are not so close together as in this MWE. Thanks again for your help!